Android date and time stuck on auto
Android os.  It is stuck on auto date and time.  When set to off, on reboot, it goes back to on. For auto date and time. I want it on manual.
Is there someone who can go Into the code , or fix it in some other way.  Thank you.
Set it to off.  But on reboot, its mysteriously back set to on.

Needs more detail: What Android version? Is it a custom ROM? Is it a ROM customized by the manufacturer (like xiaomi or Samsung do)? Why are you posting on Stack Exchage, is it a coding issue you have with your app, or regular use of the android system?
